Confusion about ground on 120V vs 240V outlet in my garage
TL;DR
I've got high resistance between the ground pin on two different outlets near each other, how should I diagnose and fix this?
Background
In my garage, I have two outlets right next to each other, a 240V NEMA 14-50 and a typical 120V NEMA 5-15. The 240V is a pretty new run. I had someone do it about 5 years ago. The 120V outlet is part of a circuit for the whole garage. It was here when we moved in. It was likely done by a previous owner in the 1970s or 80s.
This last weekend, I ran a ground wire from a metal network rack to an existing bare copper ground wire that is clamped to pipes near my water heater. The manual says the rack should be grounded and has a stud for this. When I was doing this, I took some measurements with my multimeter and I got some confusing results.
240V (NEMA 14-50) outlet is as expected
With power on I measured ~249VAC between L1 & L2, ~124V between N and either L1/L2, and a few millivolts between G and N. With power off, Resistance between G and N is ~0.1Ω. Resistance from G on this outlet to the water heater pipe is the same. This is new work, so I guess N and G are bonded at the panel, and that is connected to the same ground system as the pipes.
120V (NEMA 5-15) is confusing me
The 120V outlet is confusing me. With power on, I measure ~124VAC between L and N. 22V between G and N and 108V between G and L. With the power off, this outlet has about 1MΩ (megaohm!) between G and either L or N. N to G is s 1MΩ. Just under 1MΩ from this outlet's G to the pipe.
With both breakers off, I got just under 1MΩ between G on both outlets. The neutrals between the outlets appear well connected, 0.8Ω which I think is expected. I've read that at given panel all neutrals share a bus bar and then each circuit's L runs through the breaker.
Looking at the wiring in the box, the 120V is in the middle of the run and has the expected L, N, and bare copper in the cables entering and leaving the box behind the outlet. 240V is on it's own circuit and has the expected three large conductors and a bare copper ground.
What's going on? What to do?
Any idea what is going on? The 120V circuit does not appear to have N and G bonded at the panel.  here does appear to be a connection from the 120V circuit's G to the "house ground", but it is ~1MΩ.
This feels like a thing that should be fixed, right?  Would it be safe to connect a ground wire between the two outlets inside the wall? They're in the same stud cavity, so I don't think it would be hard for me to do. If this isn't right can/should I connect those grounds in some other way?

Have you opened up the 120V receptacle box to see whether it is (a) ground wire to screw, (b) ground wire to metal box or (c) no ground wire visible, (d) metal conduit or armored cable or (e) something else? Clearly everything is good on the 240V and in general, so the problem is likely either at the 120V receptacle box or somewhere between the 120V breaker and that box.

The 120V outlet is on a plastic box. It's mid-circuit so has cable incoming and outgoing. The cable is 3 wire, white, black and bare copper. All three are connected correctly to the outlet.
Also, I think it's this whole circuit. I have used one of those 3 light outlet testers and it tells me "open ground" on other outlets on this same circuit.

Why the votes to close? Please let me know how I can improve the question or why it isn't appropriate for the this SE.

As you probably already know, the "ghost" voltage on the 120 VAC receptacle putative ground is picked up capacitively from proximity to L. (Consider a conductor halfway between plates of a capacitor; one expects half the AC between it and each side.) Your DC measurement of ~1 MΩ to true ground is further evidence of a serious safety issue, particularly in a garage, where one might step on bare concrete or rest against a pipe or other grounded object.
The 120 VAC ground wire should be grounded at the mains entrance panel. Check at the main breaker panel that it is indeed grounded, and if not, an electrician should make repairs!
However, most likely, the 120 VAC line to the garage makes a few stops at junction boxes, perhaps with electrical outlets, and the ground wire was not connected inside one of those boxes. Perhaps it was inserted in a "stab" connector and has loosened, or broken inside a wire nut, or was wound around a non-grounded screw. That can easily be fixed:

Confirm that the main breaker panel is indeed grounded - check resistance to a metal water pipe or gas line.

Assuming it is (since the 240 VAC ground is good), shut the breaker for the 120 VAC to the garage, and tag it, lest it be turned on.

Check each outlet on that circuit between the breaker and the garage, and others in the garage.

Confirm power is off because the breaker was shut.
Unscrew and pull out the outlet and check continuity in the ground wire(s) entering and leaving. You can also check resistance referencing a (long) wire to a pipe.


Hopefully, you'll find the break, and repairs might be as simple as using a ground screw, rather than stab connector, or putting on a new wire nut.



Thanks for the detailed reply. Some followup:


From panel to a nearby ground rod or a nearby water spigot, I get 2-3Ω depending on where I probe on the panel front.


To find all the outlets on this circuit, can I use afox&hound kit, is that safe once I confirm with a NCV?


For checking G continuity on each outlet, where am I probing to do that? would it be the nearby pipe?


When I find a lack of continuity, best case is behind an outlet will show something like a break, a ground wire out of a wire nut or something similar, right?



Follow the wire back towards the panel until you find a place where the resistance between N and G is low, like less than 10 ohms on your meter.
It should be much less than 10 ohms but many meters don't real low resistances accurately)
When you find that place  check that the ground connections  are good by pulling on them etc. Check the connections both ends of
the wire that runs from "good" to "bad".

I asked this question as a comment on the answer above, but I'll ask here too. Assuming the breaker is off, is it safe to use a fox & hound type tool to find all the outlets on this circuit?
Also, house was built in 1959, I don't know the order of the outlets on the circuit. Do you have advice on how to sort that out?
Hmmm...I guess I could take all the outlets out, trace which ones connect to which, then the last one without  an "upstream" would be the run to the panel? All of this with the breaker off, of course.

start by testing all the outlets to see which ones have a working ground,  the pattern may then become obvious.

tone generator seems risky if it's not designed for use on live outlets,  if you're moving it round there's more opportunities to mess up

Use lights, radios, fans, and a buddy to map every light and outlet in  your house.   One room at a time, plug stuff in to every outlet and turn off breakers to see what's what.
Then, knowing all the switches and outlets related to the bad circuit, leave it off and measure N-G resistance everywhere.  For light switches without neutral you'll need to use a bit of wire to bring neutral from the nearest outlet on the circuit.
Then, knowing all the junction boxes on the circuit and which ones are good or bad, you can vaguely map them from the breaker panel outwards, but don't rely on that too much, and narrow the problem down to hopefully just 3 or 4 junction boxes.  And finally, inspect those for problems.
